# PHP for loop won't display table

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I'm starting to learn PHP, and I sometimes have trouble with my loops, mostly the for-loop. For some mysterious reason the content I echo in the loop simply won't show or display. When I look at the source-code after the PHP-code has been compiled there is nothing there.

Here is the code I'm using. It is supposed to display a table with 4 rows and 6 columns. But it doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<?php
$dato = date("d");

for ($teller = 0; $teller > 4; $teller++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    for ($teller2 = 0; $teller2 > 6; $teller2++) {
        echo "<td>Luke<br></td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
} 

?>
</table>
```

Comment: The loop never runs, because you specified - run loop while `$teller > 4` is true, but it is never true, because $teller is 0 at first.

Comment: The loop continues for as long as the second expression `$teller > 4` is true. You probably wanted `$teller < 4`. Useful link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php


(edit: late...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must change > by < !!!

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<?php
    $dato = date("d");

    for ($teller = 0; $teller < 4; $teller++) {
        echo "<tr>";

        for ($teller2 = 0; $teller2 < 6; $teller2++) {
            echo "<td>Luke<br></td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    } 

?>
</table>
```

Comment: “It is not that I'm so smart. But I stay with the questions much longer.”
― Albert Einstein
No problem, please accept the answer